# Not able to fetch data from firebase after doing filteration

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase structure.
[image]

I want to fetch content node based on subcategory node. Mean all content with funny subcategory should display in listview and i am doing filteration for this, but when i am fetching content node then i am getting NullPointerException.

It is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.backbtncntent);
    sharebtn = findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.contenttext);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ContentActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contentname);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    String classname = getIntent().getStringExtra("classname");
    if(classname.equals("A")){
       content = getIntent().getStringExtra("jokecontent");
       funnyJokesQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContentJokes").orderByChild("subcategory")
               .equalTo(content);
       funnyJokesQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
               for(DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   String contentdisplay = item.child("content").getValue().toString();   //in this line i am getting error
                   contentname.add(contentdisplay);
                   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {


           }

           @Override
           public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });

    }else if(classname.equals("B")){
        content = getIntent().getStringExtra("shayaricontent");
        textView.setText(content);
    }
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ContentActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    sharebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hey Read Some Interesting Content");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via"));
        }
    });
}
```

}

and i am getting this error:

```
2020-06-24 11:05:59.155 27216-27216/example.example1.shayariapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: example.example1.shayariapp, PID: 27216
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at example.example1.shayariapp.Acitivties.ContentActivity$1.onChildAdded(ContentActivity.java:52)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:202)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6962)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

Please tell me how to resolve this error. This would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're listening for child nodes, your `onChild...` methods get called with a `DataSnapshot` for each individual child. So there's no need to loop over the `snapshot.getChildren()` in there.

```
funnyJokesQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ContentJokes")
       .orderByChild("subcategory")
       .equalTo(content);
funnyJokesQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
       String contentdisplay = item.child("content").getValue(String.class);   
       contentname.add(contentdisplay);
       arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

The loop would be needed if you attached a `ValueEventListener` to the same query/reference, as in that case `onDataChange` gets called with a single `DataSnapshot` for all children.